# 2 pairs vs 2 pairs

Tags: texas-hold-em, online, betting-strategy

I am in the online NLH $0.02/$0.05 game and receive [As Tc] on SB. The player in the early position limps, I call because it seems to be an inexpensive chance to see a flop, BB checks. Then the following happens, my actions are explained:

*** FLOP *** [3d Qc 3s]

SB(me): checks <-- no ace, no tens, no bets, let them lead the flop

BB: checks

EP: checks

*** TURN *** [3d Qc 3s] [Td]

SB: bets $0.14 <-- wow, two pairs, let's protect them.

BB: folds

EP: calls $0.14

*** RIVER *** [3d Qc 3s Td] [Kd]

SB: checks <-- if he has Q or K, then I've lost, no bets.

EP: checks

*** SHOW DOWN ***

SB: shows [As Tc] (two pair, Tens and Threes)

EP: shows [Ks Jh] (two pair, Kings and Threes)

EP collected $0.41 from pot

I am wondering if I did anything wrong in this game?

Comment: When the board pairs it is not really two pairs.  If EP check kings there I want in that game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preflop:**

I like your play. These stakes people rarely fold to a raise here. You should only raise with stronger hands. Calling seems very good.

**Flop:**

Definitely standard to start with a check.

**Turn:**

If anyone had a queen you probably heard about it on the flop. Like you said, let's protect your hand and get some value from worse tens or maybe pocket 77-99 or something. I would bet 50-70% pot here since your hand isn't that strong and your are probably only protecting against straight draws, since flushdraws likely would have bet the flop. Your hand plays well if you bet. You get information, you have the betting aggression, you get value and you can comfortably check-call on most  rivers.

**River:**

Should you bluff? No, your hand is too strong. Should you valuebet? No, your hand is too weak. You have a clear check and if your opponent bets you have a decision to make. Luckily you didn't have too.

**To conclude:**

In my opinion you played your hand near perfect. I would personally bet a little less on the turn, but other than that you played the hand well.

Answer (score 0):

I would raise preflop. He would probably not fold KJ, but then you could continue "showing strength" and bet the flop. He would fold on flop, as there's no sense for him to stay in hand.